# How can I export data into Excel file I know

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

hello everyone I'm on redmine and I wanted to export all data from all tables to an excel file. if anyone has an idea.Thank you

routes.rb

```
get '/export', to: 'export#index'
```

export_controller.rb

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController

def index
    @attachments=Attachment.all
    @projects=Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xlsx
    end
end     
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>List of products</h1>
<%= link_to 'Download as .xlsx', export_path(format: :xlsx) %>
```

index.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Attachments") do |sheet|
@attachments.each do |product|
  sheet.add_row [attachment.id, attachment.filename]
 end
end
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbhI9.png)

Comment: This is always a good start: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel
But what did you tried so far?

Comment: thanks, for now I found a library axlsx but until then I can not master how it works

Comment: I suppose you can add some code, just to let people help.

Comment: I post what I did and I have a little bug he says he can not find the xlsx file

Comment: I edited the starting post

Comment: What I can see right now is: `@attachments.each do |product|` needs to be changed into `@attachments.each do |attachment|`. Try this and follow up.

Comment: yes it's an error on my part but the problem is still there he can not find the file export.xlsx